# How to add css style to php attribute

Tags: php, joomla

I have php code which generates readmore link. I need to add css `style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;padding:20px;"`
but don't know how. Any help with that:

```
if ( preg_match("/GN_readmore/", $html) && $link ) {
    $gn_readmore  = JHTML::_('link', $link, JText::_('MOD_GLOBALNEWS_READ_MORE_TITLE'));
}
```

Comment: Is this for Joomla?

Comment: Please update the title. PHP tags do not have any attributes. HTML tags do.

Comment: is for Joomla, Sir

Comment: You should add a class to those elements (via the `$attribs` parameter of the `link` method), and then handle formatting via your page stylesheet.

Comment: hi Sir, how correctly to add a class for example class="button1" ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy/paste the html output code? We may find an attribute to style. It's what @04FS is describing.

Example:
If "read more" is a title attribute, you can style it using the CSS2 [attribute~=value] selector where your attribute is "title" and the value is "read more". Be sure the title is exactly how it's shown in your html.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value_contains.asp

Sometimes you only want to style the "read more" on one page without affecting all pages. So, assign a css name to the page through the menu manager (on that menu item). If it's not a menu item on your primary navbar, then create a new (hidden) menu. A hidden men is very handy because you can have internal links with the flexibility to change that menu item another time; it then updates all internal links throughout the site like your main menu does.

Comment: there is no attribute to style,neither css file just a plain php file. I am trying to add a class for example class="button1" to $gn_readmore but no success.